# How To Evaluate $ \int \frac{\sin^2x\cdot\cos^2x}{(\sin^3x + \cos^3x)^2}\ dx $?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$
\int \frac{\sin^2x\cdot\cos^2x}{(\sin^3x + \cos^3x)^2}\ dx
$$

What I tried was

- To convert $N^r$ into $sin2x$
- To Use Identity $(a+b)^3 = (a^3 + b^3)(a^2 + b^2 - ab) $

But none of them proved useful ?

How do I evaluate this Integral ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Start with: $\sin x=\frac{\tan x}{\sec x}$ and $\sec^2 x =\tan^2 x +1$. Then,

$$\int \frac{\sin^2x\cdot\cos^2x}{(\sin^3x + \cos^3x)^2}\ dx = \int \sec^2x\,\frac{\tan^2x}{\left(\tan x+1\right)^2\left(\tan^2x-\tan x +1\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

Now use $u=\tan x$. Then use $t=\left(u+1\right)\left(u^2-u+1\right)$, sucht that

$$\int \frac{\sin^2x\cdot\cos^2x}{(\sin^3x + \cos^3x)^2}\ dx =\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t^2}.$$

Comment: The substitutions that you made were Fabulous !!! Thanks :)

Comment: @user476374684 I'm glad this helped.

Comment: BTW is there any other way also ?

Comment: @user476374684 I don't know. But notice that $$ \int \sec^2x\,\frac{\tan^2x}{\left(\tan x+1\right)^2\left(\tan^2x-\tan x +1\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x.= \int\frac{\tan^2 x \sec^2 x}{\left(1+\tan^3 x\right)^2}dx. $$